# MS OPM (Output Protection Manager) Initializing X509 chain

Tags: c++, certificate, x509

I trying to OPM (Output Protection Manager) with Visual C++ (native) using 
OPMAPI. My goal is enable HDCP session between HDMI device driver and display to protect contents through out HDMI cable.

I got an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388945(v=vs.85).aspx)

In example code there's some undocumented function about certifications.
(ValidateX509Certificate, GetPublicKeyFromCertificate)

Here follows example code.

```
    OPM_RANDOM_NUMBER random;   // Random number from driver.
    ZeroMemory(&random, sizeof(random));
    BYTE *pbCertificate = NULL; // Pointer to a buffer to hold the certificate.
    ULONG cbCertificate = 0;    // Size of the certificate in bytes.

    PUBLIC_KEY_VALUES *pKey = NULL; // The driver's public key.

    // Get the driver's certificate chain + random number
    HRESULT hr = pVideoOutput->StartInitialization(
        &random,
        &pbCertificate,
        &cbCertificate );

    // Validate the X.509 certificate. (Not shown.)
    hr = ValidateX509Certificate(pbCertificate, cbCertificate);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the public key from the certificate. (Not shown.)
    hr = GetPublicKeyFromCertificate(
        pbCertificate,
        cbCertificate,
        &pKey );
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=KO-KR&k=k(%22OPMAPI%2fIOPMVIDEOOUTPUT%3a%3aSTARTINITIALIZATION%22);k(%22IOPMVIDEOOUTPUT%3a%3aSTARTINITIALIZATION%22);k(STARTINITIALIZATION);k(DevLang-%22C%2B%2B%22);k(TargetOS-WINDOWS)&rd=true), `IOPMVideoOutput::StartInitialization()` retrieves random number and X509 certificate chain (pbCertificate).

`ValidateX509Certificate()` and `GetPublicKeyFromCertificate()` function are not shown.

Could anyone explain to me the way to write above two function please?

Or I want to know how decode X.509 cert chain data (DER) into CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT.

Answer (score 3):

The StartInitialization function returns the complete certificate chain of the driver as signed PKCS7 data with DER encoding. This is not the usual X509 certificate with DER encoding we commonly deal with. Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the MSDN pages.

The certificates/certificate chain can be extracted from signed PKCS7 DER using any crypto library/framework. We can verify and get the public key using Microsoft crypto framework with the folloing steps.

1. Get certificate chain with [CryptGetMessageCertificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379962(v=vs.85).aspx) function
2. Optionally you can verify the certificate chain as explained ["Performing X.509 Certificate Verification with CryptoAPI"](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+10.+Public+Key+Infrastructure/10.6+Performing+X.509+Certificate+Verification+with+CryptoAPI/)
3. Get the subject certificate [CERT_CONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377189(v=vs.85).aspx) as explained in Step 2. The subject public key can be retrieved from [pCertInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377200(v=vs.85).aspx) of CERT_CONTEXT.

It is much easier (at least I feel like) to do with OpenSSL which is explained ["how to Read the certificates file from the PKCS7.p7b certificate file usind openssl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369096/how-to-read-the-certificates-file-from-the-pkcs7-p7b-certificate-file-usind-open). It shows how to retrieve the certificates and you can easily retrieve public key using X509_get_pubkey function.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm successfully getting the cert store via CryptGetMessageCertificates, and I'm able to enumerate the certs in the store via CertEnumCertificatesInStore. But, with 3 certificates in the store (2 issued by MSFT, 1 from Nvidia) I'm lost now as to how to identify which of these certificates is the leaf with the public key I really care about (i.e. the key that would be returned by GetPublicKeyFromCertificate).

Comment: My hunch is the last cert in the enumeration is the leaf/end (the one from NVIDIA). I attempted to confirm by calling CertGetCertificateChain using this last cert (and the basic config described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382042(v=vs.85).aspx)). I expected that using the last certificate, I would get a chain containing the other two certificates, but pChainContext->cChain = 1 for all 3 of my certificates - so now just more confused.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code to implement the missed function mentioned [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/opm-example-code), and show how to use OPM and the related crypto implementation based on the standard window API, https://github.com/wangf1978/D3DTest, CryptoUtil.cpp/OPMSession.cpp