# How to extract CA, multiple CAs and public certificate/key from PKCS7 programmatically?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

From a pkcs7b file that is PEM format, I need to extract one CA and/or if there are multiple CAs, into a single PEM file.

Likewise, if there is public certificate, I need to extract the same into another PEM file.

I see good example here:
[How to Read the certificates file from the PKCS7.p7b certificate file using openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369096/how-to-read-the-certificates-file-from-the-pkcs7-p7b-certificate-file-using-open/6395941)

But I am unable to decide from X509, which part should be for CA and public certificate.
These files I need to feed to nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we X509_check_ca() that would distinguish if its CA or not. 
Alternative, to match subject name with issuer name